Projective plane curves from Fulton
I am confused by one of the paragraphs at the beginning of Chapter 5, Projective Plane Curves of the book Algebraic Curves by Fulton. Here let me copy it:
"If we are considering a finite set of points $P_1,\cdots,P_n\in\mathbb{P}^2$, we can always find a line $L$ that does not pass through any of the points. If $F$ is a curve of degree $d$, we let $F_*=F/(L)^d\in k(\mathbb{P}^2)$. This $F_*$ depends on $L$, but if $L'$ were another choice, then $F/(L')^d=(L/L')^dF_*$ and $L/L'$ is a unit in each $\mathcal{O}_{P_i}(\mathbb{P}^2)$. Note also that we may always find a projective change of coordinates so that the line $L$ be comes the line $Z$ at infinity: then under the natural identification of $k(\mathbb{A}^2)$ with $k(\mathbb{P}^2)$, this $F_*$ is the same as the old $F_*=F(X,Y,1)$."
My question. I am not sure how is this the same as $F_*$. Even though I understand the arguments before the very last one. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.
